# Bash: return code in if statement causes unexpected behavior

Tags: bash, cmp

I'm using the using the `cmp` command to check if two files are identical. I would like to stick the command into a one line if statement but it's not working as expected. When comparing two files and one the files doesn't exist, `cmp` returns 2. Since 2 is non-zero, I would expect the if statement to evaluate to true, but it does not and I don't understand why.

I want to write something like:

```
if cmp -s tickets.txt tickets_orig.txt; then
  #do stuff here
fi
```

because I find it short, sweet and more intuitive. Is this possible?

I was able to create a workaround by using `$?`, but I don't understand why the code below will evaluate to true and the code above will evaluate to false when the command returns 2:

```
cmp -s tickets.txt tickets_orig.txt
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  #do stuff here
fi
```

Comment: "Since 2 is non-zero, I would expect the if statement to evaluate to true" - `0` indicates success in Bash.  Your `if` block will only execute if the files are identical.  Invert the condition: `if ! cmp -s tickets.txt tickets_orig.txt; then...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exit status ($?) = 0 means success in shell logic, it allows to define different error codes 1 to 127 for anormal status

```
if command; then #...
```

is equivalent to

```
command;
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then #...
```

and

```
command;
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then #...
```

equivalent to

```
if ! command; then #...
```